# Confusion about the uniqueness of an SDE

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose we are given a SDE of the form
$$
dX_t=\sigma(t,X_t)dW_t + b(t,X_t)dt,\quad X_0=\xi.
$$

For simplicity, let $\xi$ be a constant.

My understanding is that

- Strong solution: for a given probability space, filtration, and a Brownian motion (BM), if there exists $X$ that solves the above SDE, then $X$ is a strong solution.
- Weak solution: if we can find a probability space, filtration, a BM, and $X$, then we say that the a tuple of these is a weak solution.

For the uniqueness, we say that

- Unique in law: if the law of $X$ is unique. (E.g. a BM $B$ and $-B$ both solve the Tanaka SDE, and their laws are the same)
- Pathwise uniqueness: if there are two solutions $X$ and $X'$, then $\mathbb{P}(X_t=X_t',\forall t)$.

My confusion is related to Ito's theorem and Yamada-Watanabe Theorem. Ito's theorem says that if $\sigma$ and $b$ are Lipshitz and of linear growth, then the solution exists and is unique. Yamada-Watanabe says that a weak solution + pathwise uniqueness is equivalent to  the existence of a unique strong solution.

My confusions are as follows.

- In Ito's theorem, what does it mean by ``unique''? Is it pathwise uniqueness?
- In Ito's theorem, what does it mean by ``solution''? Is is strong solution?
- If Ito's theorem is about a strong and pathwise unique solution, then since strong solution is weak, Yamada-Watanabe seems to be moot.

I consulted Karatzas-Shereve, Rogers-Williams, and Klenke, but they use slightly different terminology and I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed globally-Lipschitz regularity gives you strong-solution and  strong-uniqueness (see Karatzas-Shreve 5.1 "Strong solutions"). As explained in Karatzas-Shreve the difference between pathwise and strong-uniqueness is:

- Pathwise uniqueness is said to hold  among solutions that spend zero time at 0 if whenever $(X,W), (X,\tilde{W} )$ are two weak solutions with  a common Brownian motion $W$ (relative to **possibly different filtrations** $\mathcal{F}_{t},\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_{t}$) on a common probability space and with common initial value, then $P(Xt = \tilde{X}_t \text{ for all }t \geq 0) = 1$.
- Strong uniqueness almost the same above with the extra assumption "with respect to a common Brownian motion $W$ and **with the same filtration**" $\mathcal{F}_{t}$.

One theorem of Yamada-Watanabe proves that one can lift a weak-solution with pathwise-uniqueness to a strong solution.

[image]

They also prove that a strong-solution is possible with a weaker requirement on the coefficients (described in Karatzas-Shreve as you mentioned) (note that below they actually mean strong-uniqueness) eg. in  [LECTURE NOTES ON THE YAMADA–WATANABE CONDITION
FOR THE PATHWISE UNIQUENESS OF SOLUTIONS OF
CERTAIN STOCHASTIC DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS](https://www.fam.tuwien.ac.at/%7Eschmock/notes/Yamada-Watanabe.pdf).

For example, Revuz-Yor never uses the phrase "strong-uniqueness" but instead just talks about "pathwise-uniqueness" (which they define having the same filtration i.e. the strong uniqueness from Karatzas-Shrever).

[image]

Comment: So, under the Karatzas-Shreve definition, strong uniqueness implies pathwise uniqueness? Is it possible that there is a pathwise unique weak solution but a strong solution, which exists by Yamada-Watanabe, is not strong unique?

Comment: @keepfrog other way around, if an SDE satisfies pathwise-uniqueness then it also gives strong-uniqueness because you can take $\mathcal{F}^1_{t}=\mathcal{F}^2_{t}$. Pathwise-uniqueness says if you have two solutions X1,X2 with filtrations $\mathcal{F}^1_{t},\mathcal{F}^2_{t}$, then they are in fact equal $P[X^1_t=X^2_t, \forall t\geq 0]=1$.

Comment: So Yamada-Watanabe theorem is more demanding i.e. to yield strong-existence one needs both weak-solution and pathwise-uniqueness.

Comment: also as they  mention in (5.3) remark 3.3 In Karatzas-Shreve, the Lipschitz-theorems can also be done with pathwise-uniqueness.